# swiftui passing variable into antoher view

Tags: swift, user-interface, variables

Hey below you find my source code. 
What i wanna do is:

After the Json is extracted I want that it will be accessable in a other view...
Please help me...

I Mean the extracted Value: "\n (users.Name)"

So I want simply the response data into a other view...

```
struct User: Codable {
let Name: String
}

let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.178.26/iso/loginserv.php")
                guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

                var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"

                let postString = "user=\(self.user)&pass=\(self.pass)";

                request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                    (data, response, error) in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error took place \(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let data = data else {return}

                    do{
                        let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                        print("Response data Name: \n \(users.Name)")


                        if !(data.isEmpty) {
                            self.signedIn = true
                        }

                    }catch let jsonErr{
                        print(jsonErr)
                    }

                }


                task.resume()
```

[All i want is to get the marked thing into another view...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzBaQ.png)

Comment: An important question is: How do you want this new view to work? Are you looking to have the view do a Navigation push, like tapping on a detail indicator, or are you wanting to overlay a custom view on your existing view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use Singleton design pattern.

Basically you create a class that is instanced a single time only, with a global static property. That property will be used to pass info from one view to another.

So, first create a Singleton class (as a simple Swift file) and define a static instance, like this:

```
class Singleton {

      static let instance = Singleton()

      private init() {

      }
}
```

Now, create and initialize the variable you want to share between views, for example the string `name`:

```
class Singleton {

      static let instance = Singleton()

      private init() {

      }

      var name = ""

}
```

Now, in your code, attribute `users.Name` to it:

```
                do{
                    let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                    print("Response data Name: \n \(users.Name)")

                    Singleton.instance.name = users.Name

                    if !(data.isEmpty) {
                        self.signedIn = true
                    }

                }catch let jsonErr{
                    print(jsonErr)
                }
```

Now, to access this info in another view, just use `Singleton.instance.name`.

Comment: This is way long and complex

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct like this

```
struct structFittings {
    static var collectedWorks: Bool = false
    static var collected: String = "notcollected"
    static var failclicked: Bool = false
}
```

Access like this

```
structFittings.collectedWorks
```

Any where in the app